# iOS Swift Update text label after 1 second

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Trying to update a label after 1 second. Am using the sleep function but the app is loading and not updating the text field on the fly.

code is:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    beginCountdown()
}

func beginCountdown() {

    for var i = 5; i >= 0; i-- {

        println("Time until launch \(i)")

        var county:String = "\(i)"

        countdownLabel.text = county
        sleep(1)
    }

}
```

The outlet is correct, I know I'm missing something. Thanks

Comment: You should use an NSTimer for this, have the timer repeat every second and update the label. Then turn it off after a count to five.

Comment: At the end - I get the println fine

Comment: NEVER use `sleep` on the main thread, ever.

Comment: The UI can only draw once it gets a chance to execute. What your code is doing is blocking while the loop executes, the UI cannot update until the code is unblocked, therefore it is not having the effect you desire and your UI code is not updating during the countdown, only after its finished. You need to use NSTimer, this will allow the code to unblock and run during the countdown and not after it, doing this will allow th UI to draw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `sleep()` function as this will suspend the main thread and cause your app to become non-responsive.  `NSTimer` is one way to achieve this.  It will dispatch a function at a specified time in the future.

For example -

```
var countdown=0
var myTimer: NSTimer? = nil

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {     
    countdown=5
    myTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector:"countDownTick", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    countdownLabel.text = "\(countdown)"
}

func countDownTick() {
    countdown--

    if (countdown == 0) {
       myTimer!.invalidate()
       myTimer=nil
    }

    countdownLabel.text = "\(countdown)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul and to the other guys - used the NSTimer code above and got the expected result.

Comment: It will not freez UI. mean while you can do another task on ui. I was searching something like this code that works as background in a separate thread. but by this way my problem solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You really **shouldn't** use `sleep` as it will block the main thread and so freeze the UI, which means you will never see your label updated (and far worse things).

You can achieve what you're trying to do using `NSTimer`.

```
var timer: NSTimer!
var countdown: Int = 0

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.countdown = 5
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "updateCountdown", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateCountdown() {
    println("Time until launch \(self.countdown)")
    countdownLabel.text = "\(self.countdown)"

    self.countdown--

    if self.countdown == 0 {
        self.timer.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.0

```
var countdown=0
var myTimer: Timer? = nil

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     countdown=5
    myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector:  #selector(Dashboard.countDownTick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    lbl_CustomerName.text = "\(countdown)"
}

func countDownTick() {
    countdown = countdown - 1
    //For infinite time
    if (countdown == 0) {
        countdown = 5
      //till countdown value  
        /*myTimer!.invalidate()
        myTimer=nil*/
    }

    lbl_CustomerName.text = "\(countdown)"
}
```